# How to pass a parameter to the class by creating a class from a string

Tags: php, class

My question title may be logically wrong, because I do not know how to explain it :)

Here are example of what I need. I have master classe and two another classes which this masters class creates. This two classes have constructors with parameters and I do not know how to pass this parameters.

```
class Master {

    function __construct() {
        $this->setup_settings();
        $this->load_classes();
    }

    public function setup_settings() {
        $this->settings['classes'] = array( 'Class_A', 'Class_B' );
    }

    public function load_classes() {
        foreach( $this->settings['classes'] as $class) {
            new $class; //Here are problem!
        }
    }

}

class Class_A {

    function __construct( $setiings ) {
        $this->settings = $settings;
    }

}
class Class_B {

    function __construct( $setiings ) {
        $this->settings = $settings;
    }

}
```

**In this case I have an error:**

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for Class_A ::__construct()
```

I understanding why it is. But how to pass parameters to this class in this way (when class names are in array)? When I am creating string and passing it I have an error: class cant be converted to string.

Comment: `new $class('some arguments');`?

Comment: Yes you right. Simple answer for my stupid question :) I thought It is impossible to pass parameters in this way. Tryed many more other... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the arguments in parens `($args)`.

```
$instance = new $objectName($args);
```

`ClassA` and `ClassB` both have constructors that expect a parameter called `$settings`. BTW, you misspelled it there.

Answer (score 1):

You would initialize the object as you would do if you wrote new Class_A() instead of $class:

```
public function load_classes() {
    foreach ($this->settings['classes'] as $class) {
        $obj = new $class($this->settings);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to fix your variable names here:

```
class Class_A {

    function __construct( $settings // not setiings ) {
        $this->settings = $settings;
    }

}
class Class_B {

    function __construct( $settings // not setiings ) {
        $this->settings = $settings;
    }

}
```

In order to pass the variables to the classes, you can do:

```
public function load_classes() {
        foreach( $this->settings['classes'] as $class) {
            new $class('helloworld'); // or any variable you'd like
        }
    }
```

However, note that since you're creating a new class, but not assigning it to any variable, you likely won't be able to see the result.

Try this instead if you'd like to see results:

```
class Master {
    private $result;

    function __construct() {
        $this->setup_settings();
        $result = $this->load_classes();
        $this->result = $result;
    }

    public function getResult()
   {
        return $this->result;
   }

    public function setup_settings() {
        $this->settings['classes'] = array( 'Class_A', 'Class_B' );
    }

    public function load_classes() {
        foreach( $this->settings['classes'] as $class) {
            $a = new $class('hello');
        $arr[] = $a; // store it in an array
        }

        return $arr; // return the array
    }

}

class Class_A {

    function __construct( $settings ) {
        $this->settings = $settings;
    }

}
class Class_B {

    function __construct( $settings ) {
        $this->settings = $settings;
    }
}

$master = new Master();
var_dump($master->getResult());
```